# Magento 2 OAuth authentication fails when activating an integration

Tags: magento2, api, integration

I want to create an integration. I have added an integration in System > Extensions > Integrations.
I have added Callback and Identity URL.

When saving, it generates a Consumer Key and Consumer Secret. When I click Activate, the login screen that I added in callback URL it opens and after login,

I get no messages or exceptions in any of the logs in Magento (debug.log, system.log, exception.log) or in any of my external application's log. After the login screen it will says that

"Sorry, we couldn't establish a connection to your Magento store
Please try to 'Activate' or 'Reauthorize' the integration again."

Error reference 160df1fe

Please Help me about this.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Please let me know if you find any resolution. Also it looks like someone has started a Uservoice idea for this issue. You might want to go and upvote it here: https://clickanddrop.uservoice.com/forums/399930-general/suggestions/43058421-make-integration-with-magento-working-again